# $3 \sin(\sqrt{x}) = x$ cant find non zero solution to this

Tags: trigonometry

Hi i have been playing with this equation, complex form of the sine, polynomial expansion trying to find the non zero pole, and I am failing.

$$ 3\sin(\sqrt{x})=x$$

Comment: According to WolframAlpha it's about $2.9657$.

Comment: Read  my response to Chris Culter.

Comment: If you don't want lots of numerical solutions, you should say so **in your question.** There's no analytical solution.

Comment: I will say so next time, but since you are saying this after I replied to all the other users, and got an answer, I find it redundant. Nonetheless thank you for the memorandum.

Answer (score 2):

For transcendental equations like this one, you cannot expect analytical solutions (this is already the case for $x=\cos(x)$) and numerical methods are required.

Proably the simplest would be Newton method for finding the zero of

$$f(x)=3 \sin \left(\sqrt{x}\right)-x$$ $$f'(x)=\frac{3 \cos \left(\sqrt{x}\right)}{2 \sqrt{x}}-1$$ So, the iterates will be given by 
$$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}$$ Graphing, you can notice that the solution is close to $3$. So, let use use $x_0=3$ to get the following iterates
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & x_n \\
 0 & 3 \\
 1 & 2.965830999 \\
 2 & 2.965714903 \\
 3 & 2.965714902
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: Ok i was excepcting to hear that this is not possible indeed. Thanks a lot. Have a good night.

Answer (score 0):

$x = 2.96571490164526781847756898\ldots$

Source: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3+sin(sqrt(x))%3Dx

Comment: I already solved this by numeric methods, I am trying to find an analytic solution.

Comment: If there is a possible one, and I am saying this with a lot of doubt, I do not know if it is possible.